# Chrome Developer Tools places breakpoint at incorrect location

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-os

I'm working on debugging the script of a page I visit (I'm looking to modify its functionality with Tampermonkey) and I am trying to set breakpoints on some code. This code was minified, so I clicked the "prettify" button and now I can use a formatted version of it instead for debugging.

The first breakpoint was able to be set at the right line, but the next would not stick and would instead appear about a hundred lines further down. This seems to be a bug that has been plaguing Chrome Developer Tools for a while and complaints keep on popping up about it. How can I get it to set breakpoints where I want them to be set?

ETA: The breakpoint goes back to the right place when it is DISABLED, then goes back to the wrong when it is re-enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Minifiers apply various optimizations on your code, such as combining concatenated statements into a single expression using the [Comma Operator](https://gideonpyzer.com/blog/javascript-the-comma-operator/). If you try to break in the middle of that expression, the debugger will jump to the next statement instead. See the example below from a script on this page.

[image: Jumping breakpoint]

There is some discussion on implementing sub-expression breakpoints into V8 [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451015), but this hasn't been implemented as of yet.